# Android: Unable to cut out the overlay image and the photo within the overlay

Tags: android, android-image, android-bitmap, android-crop

I have the following code where you can combine the photo data and the overlay image as
one bitmap then save it. The problem is that I dont know how to cropout only the overlay image
and the photo image within the overlay image. I dont want to save the preview image outside of the overlay image.
It would be great if you can help me out with a sample or tips! I would love to hear from you!

I want to merge the data of the callback with the mOverlayLayout, its a RelativeLayout with a ImageView of a 
costume where you can place your face.

```
jpegCallback = (byte[] data, Camera camera) -> {
            Bitmap tmp_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray (data, 0, data.length);

            int width = tmp_bitmap.getWidth ();
            int height = tmp_bitmap.getHeight ();
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix ();
            int angleToRotate = CameraUtil.getRoatationAngle(CameraMainActivity.this,
                    Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
            angleToRotate = angleToRotate + mPortrait;
            matrix.postRotate (angleToRotate);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap (tmp_bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
            Bitmap baseBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

            mOverlayLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            mOverlayLayout.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap overlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(mOverlayLayout.getDrawingCache());
            mOverlayLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);


            Bitmap mergedImage = mCameraUtil.combineImages(overlay, baseBitmap);
```

// This is the method to combine the images

```
            public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap frame, Bitmap image) {
        //Base frame source
        Rect src = new Rect(0,0, frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
        RectF dst = new RectF(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(image);

        comboImage.drawBitmap(frame, src, dst, paint);
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        return image;
}
```

//For example how will I crop out only the imageview overlay and the photo data within the overlay?

[sample image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seqQl.jpg)

Comment: ok so what do you want to do with that little yellow bird?

Comment: I only want the image of the Yellowbird and the face part to be saved. I dont know how to cut out only those parts.

Comment: face? you mean finger? i dont see any face here? post another image and draw the thin red rectangle indicating the area you want to save

Comment: I want to save the only the yellow bird and the face(finger) part. actually the yellowbird image is a square. I want to make a overlay composite camera app :) –